# Magento 2.3.0 Admin Reviews cannot add

Tags: admin, magento2.3, review, product-review

I have setup multi-website in one magento. All the website working fine.

Now, I have tried to add review from admin but its gives below error.

```
A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
```

[image]

I have enabled default ratings named Price, Quality and value for all the stores.

Please help me to how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check the Developer Console, Console log files

Comment: Hello @HIrenKadivar how to check console?

Comment: please check on var/log exception or system log ans also check brower console log

Comment: I checked browser console and its return with 404 code.
`http://magento230.com/admin/review/product/jsonProductInfo/id/1/key/dd74b9bb4b64d582f7c0e4c0df34d07741d562fa17a6acb4e376fb95c5c60161/?isAjax=true` 404 Bad request

Comment: I have the same problem when adding an image to a product that is larger than 1MB

Comment: @HirenShah
check this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20385

Comment: @HIrenKadivar and for my problem? could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply.

I found same issue with my magento version 2.3.0 and found below solution. Might be this will help you.

I have overwrite vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Adminhtml/Add.php file into my custom module and made below changes

```
loadProductData : function() {
jQuery.ajax({
    //type: "POST",
    type: "GET",    //  insted of "POST" I replaced it with "GET"
```

Thanks